# How to find the value of a dictionary when a dictionary variable is put in a list and random is run

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, when a dictionary variable is put in a list and randomized, is there a way to get only the key or values? I know I need to use key() to get the value of key, but I need to use a dictionary variable.key, is there a way?

```
import random

SPADE_A = {'SPADE':'CARD','A':'NUM'}
HEART_A = {'HEART':'CARD','A':'NUM'}
CLUB_A = {'CLUB':'CARD','A':'NUM'}
DIAMOND_A ={'DIAMOND':'CARD','A':'NUM'}
SPADE_2 = {'SPADE':'CARD',2:'NUM'}
HEART_2 = {'HEART':'CARD',2:'NUM'}
CLUB_2 = {'CLUB':'CARD',2:'NUM'}
DIAMOND_2 = {'DIAMOND':'CARD',2:'NUM'}
SPADE_3 = {'SPADE':'CARD',3:'NUM'}
HEART_3 = {'HEART':'CARD',3:'NUM'}
CLUB_3 = {'CLUB':'CARD', 3:'NUM'}
DIAMOND_3 = {'DIAMOND':'CARD',3:'NUM'}
card = [SPADE_A,HEART_A,DIAMOND_A,CLUB_A,SPADE_2,HEART_2,DIAMOND_2,CLUB_2,
        SPADE_3,HEART_3,DIAMOND_3,CLUB_3]

table = random.sample(card,4)
print(table.key())
```

```
I don't know where to get the value of the dictionary.
```

Comment: you seem to have the key and the value reversed. Usually I would expect that your dictionary looks like `{'CARD': 'SPADE', 'NUM': 'A'}` but you have it the other way around. If you make the dictionary this way, then you can do `table['CARD']` and `table['NUM']` to access the values. There's no need to actually assign each value to a separate variable, just directly create a list of dictionaries where you put your data

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am aware that keys and values ​​have changed. However, since I only know how to subtract the key value and I don't know how to subtract the values, I changed it for a while to find the answer.

Comment: but what is the purpose of a dictionary where the relevant info is the key and the value is always the same? You want it the other way around, otherwise you could instead use sets of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is the color : Spade, Heart... and the second element is the number, something like `deck = {("CLUB", 3), ("HEART", 6), ("DIAMOND", 8)}`. You can then for example access the first card number doing `deck[0][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to ask "What's the correct way of doing this?" rather than "How can I do this the wrong way?"

You have figured out something fundamental is wrong - your data structure doesn't fit the problem. What would work better, given what you've shown, is a list.

For a deck of cards there's several use cases.  Here's how you can easily create a complete deck of cards.

```
import random
import itertools

numbers = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
suits = ['club', 'diamond', 'heart', 'spade']
cards = list(itertools.product(numbers, suits))
```

Your cards are in order from Ace of clubs to King of spades.

```
print(cards[0:5])
[('Ace', 'club'), ('Ace', 'diamond'), ('Ace', 'heart'), ('Ace', 'spade'), ('2', 'club')]
```

You can deal five cards like:

```
for number, suit in random.sample(cards, 5):
    print(f'{number} of {suit}s')
4 of diamonds
10 of diamonds
3 of spades
Jack of spades
9 of clubs
```

Managing your deck to avoid problems like dealing the same card twice is a different problem. For that you may want to pop the cards from the deck as you go.